# How can I make a pendant?

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I saw a really nice pendant and I want to make it in blender 2.8. I a begginer and I don't know how to do it from start to finish. Here is a picture of the pendandt. Should I model it in the sculpting mode? How?[image]

Comment: I definitely wouldn't star with sculpting, its a symmetrical, so you will need to actualy model only a half and you cant cut it into segments. If you have front view that would help a lot or draw it by your self on a paper for reference and model it according to that. Sculpting can be used for the symbols in the middle and for final touches to it look less technical and more handmade.

Comment: If you are starting with blender watch a few "tutorials" on basic modieling, to get accuainted with the tools to edit vertices/edges and faces. Don't sculpt until you have the basic shape resolved. Sculpt only to get the very fine details and irregularities.